# How do Forestry Bee Comb production chance work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

For example, Exotic bee has a 30% chance in the database to produce a Silky Comb, but the Edenic bee (one evolution up) only has a 20% chance. I also notice that they have differing production speeds - does this have an effect on the so-called 'base' chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article on [Bee Breeding](http://ftbwiki.org/Bee_Breeding#Production) in the FTB Wiki has a very good explanation on how comb production works.

> Every bee tick (550 minecraft ticks, or 27.5 seconds), the bee has a
>   chance to produce items. This is calculated separately for each item
>   type the bee produces. The chance is given by the following formula:
>
> ```
> P = (bee speed) * (production modifier) * (item probability)
> ```
>
> P is the probability of the bee producing items during this tick. If P
>   >= 1.0, then the bee will always produce items every bee tick. Bee speed is determined by the "Speed" trait of the queen, using the
>   following table for the conversion:
>
> ```
> Speed trait    Bee speed
> Slowest        0.3
> Slower         0.6
> Slow           0.8
> Normal         1.0
> Fast           1.2
> Faster         1.4
> Fastest        1.7
> ```
>
> The production modifier is determined by the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Set the production modifier to 0.1 for an apiary, or 1.0 for an alveary
> 2. For each default Forestry frame (Untreated Frame, Impregnated Frame or Proven Frame), multiply production chance by two
>
> The last variable, item probability, is a constant value for each type
>   of item produced for each bee. For example, for industrious bees, the
>   item probability is 0.2 for honey combs, and 0.15 for pollen.
>
> The total chance of producing an item with a given queen is acquired
>   by multiplying the production modifier by the base chance of producing
>   an item (e.g. 20% for honey combs, 15% for pollen) by the speed trait
>   of the queen (e.g., multiply by 1.7 for a queen with Fastest Worker)
>   and then doubling the resultant value once for every frame present in
>   the Apiary/Alveary.
>
> (Production Modifier * Base Item Production Chance * Speed Trait of
>   Queen) * 2^Quantity of Default Forestry Frames = Chance of Producing
>   Given Item per Cycle with Given Bee
>
> Once every 27.5 seconds (the
>   length of a cycle) this formula is checked and the bee has a chance of
>   producing an item. Any frames in an Apiary/Alveary also take one point
>   of damage, five if in an Alveary. If the resultant value of the above
>   formula is greater than or equal to one, the bee will always produce
>   one item every 27.5 seconds it is in an Apiary or Alveary.

Comment: so what this is saying is that the species of bee is irrelevant to the production speed - it only determines the default productivity speed (which can be changed via extrabees).